# SIMD: Flip sign of four packed integer

Tags: c++, simd

Let's say I have four packed ints.

```
__m128i val = _mm_set_epi32(42,64,123,456);
```

What's the fastest way to flip the sign (multiply by -1) of the four integers in val?

Comment: You mean, to turn 42 into -42, etc.?

Comment: And you want to do that once you have the `val` set already? I mean, you want a function that transforms the `val` into a `val` obtained from the same integers, but with inverted signs?

Comment: did you try sub it from 0?  assuming you're using mmx intrinsics?

Comment: @TravisG edited as it seems you want to flip the *sign* and not to flip the *sign bits* (which is a *different* thing)

Comment: @Anton Kovalenko Where's the difference?

Comment: On a two's complement CPU (i.e. every real, existing CPU), the difference between flipping the _sign_ and flipping the _sign bit_ is 31 bits being different (of a 32 bit word).

Comment: @Damon Yep, that's true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subtract your actual values from a set of `{0,0,0,0}` [that's probably the fastest], you can XOR with {-1,-1,-1,-1} "all ones" and then add {1,1,1,1}. Or you can multiply by -1.

Comment: Yes, subtract from 0 seems to be the fastest. Can't easily multiply by -1 since I only have SSE2 available (no mul_epi32), which means that I have to create an epi16 with 0,-1,0,-1,0,-1... and so forth first.

Answer (score 3):

Just subtract from 0, e.g.

```
val = _mm_sub_epi32(_mm_set1_epi32(0), val);
```